# Проблема с генератором случайных паролей на discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Пытаюсь сделать генератор паролей для дискорд бота на pyhton 3. Имеется вот такой код:

```
import discord
import json
import requests
import random
import string

s1 = string.ascii_letters
s2 = string.digits
s3 = string.punctuation

s = s1 + s2 + s3
pas = ""

for i in range(15):
    p = random.choice(s)
    pas += p
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('!pass'):
        await message.channel.send(f"Пароль {pas}")
```

При команде !pass генерируется и выдается один пароль. При последующей команде !pass выдается этот же пароль. Как можно сделать так чтобы при команде !pass выдавался уже другой пароль?

Comment: поправьте пожалуйста отступы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import random
import string

def get_pass() -> str:
    letters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    return "".join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(15))
```

---

**PS.** еще можно вместо `choice` использовать функцию [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) выполнить, тогда не нужен будет `for _ in range(15)`, т.к. в `choices` можно передать параметр `k`, что указывает количество случайных значений

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, не разбираюсь в модуле discord, но генератор паролей можно реализовать так, затем просто запихать в функцию и сделать выполнение этой функции при вводе команды.

```
import random
import string

n = 0
l = ""
ascii = string.ascii_letters + str(string.digits)
while n <= 8: # где 8 - количество символов в нике
    l += random.choice(ascii)
    n += 1
print(l)
```

Comment: Зачем приводить к строке `string.digits`? Там и так строка: `digits = '0123456789'`. Еще, `ascii` это название встроенной функции, лучше не называть так переменные: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii. Мне кажется цикл while тут лишний, проще через генератор сделать: `text = "".join(random.choice(ascii) for _ in range(8))`

Answer (score 0):

Вот короч функция:

```
from random import choices
import string
def genpass(length):
    return ''.join(choices(string.ascii_letters + s2 = string.digits + s3 = string.punctuation, k=length))
```

Comment: А что именно с этой функцией необходимо сделать

Comment: А что именно с этой функцией необходимо сделать

Comment: @ИгорьМокривский Что хочешь ;) просто вызываешь ее где надо в коде и все тут ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, у вас там фигня с копипастой, типа: `+ s2 =`